# Godot 3.5 NavigationAgent2D is_target_reached & is_navigation_finished always return False

Tags: godot-3

I have this code in which i attached to a KinematicBody2D:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

onready var nav_agent := $NavAgent


func _physics_process(delta):
   
    var move_direction = position.direction_to(nav_agent.get_next_location())
    var velocity = move_direction * 25
    move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)

    

func move_to(coord:Vector2):
    nav_agent.set_target_location(coord)
    print(position,nav_agent.get_next_location())
    print(coord)
    print(_arrived_to_location())

func _arrived_to_location():
    return nav_agent.is_target_reached()
```

The problem is that even though i haven't sent any coordinate to the object the function  `is_target_reached` & `is_navigation_finished` always return False.

This is the output when move_to method is called:

```
(379, 208)(379, 208)
(533.471619, 115.5)
False
```

I see two issues:

1. Even after setting the target location to a new coordinate, get_next_location function return the same position of the object actually has.
2. `is_target_reached` & `is_navigation_finished` always return False.

Did i miss something to send/configure to the navigationAgent2D?

Comment: Maybe you already did this, but make sure you've either added a NavigationRegion2D to your scene and drawn a polygon for the navigable area, or set up a TileMap with navigation configured.